# In app purchase testing in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift3, app-store-connect, sandbox

I am using **Xcode 8.0, Swift 3.0** and testing in app purchases in my iPad. **I want to test in app purchases using sandbox user.**

**There is no account added in device's Setting**

The Problem is I am not getting product list in response of product request code.
Please take a look on my code:

```
let PRODUCT_ID_MY_PRODUCT = "com.company.ProjectName.MyProduct"
// The ProducID in this code and ProducID on iTunes are the SAME. ✔️

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if productID == nil {
        productID = PRODUCT_ID_MY_PRODUCT
    }
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    startPurchases()
}

func startPurchases() {
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productIDs = NSSet(object: self.productID!)

        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }
}


// Delegate Methods for SKProductsRequest
func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let count : Int = response.products.count
       // THE PROBLEM IS HERE.. I AM GETTING COUNT IS ZERO.. MEANS response.products returning null ARRAY
    if (count>0) {
        let validProducts = response.products
        for aProduct in validProducts {
            print(aProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIAlertView(title: "Purchase !", message: "Product not available", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
            return
        })
    }
}
```

So..... That's the problem: I am getting response.products null (no data in array) so Please help me to find the solution. You can see the comments in code:
// THE PROBLEM IS HERE.. I AM GETTING COUNT IS ZERO.. MEANS response.products returning null ARRAY

I created products over iTunes Connect. You can see the image below. All the products are in **"Ready to Submit" state.**

There is some warning on iTunes

```
Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. 
Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.


Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase 
has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be 
submitted using the table below.
```

[image: In-App Purchases iOS iTunes Connect Ready to submit state]

And

I also created **Sendbox user for testing** In-App Purchases. See the image below:

[image: Sendbox test user for In-App Purchases iOS itunes]

Did I miss something? Or what is the error? And where is error? **I want to test in app purchases using sandbox user**

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes @MaximShoustin... please see my answer below. If you are facing the same issue, I think you are missing some small part.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this. There are some points need to careful about. See below:

- Make sure your developer account did the paid application contract. see image below:
- Create Products on the iTunes Connect.
- Implement In-App-Purchases code and configuration settings.
- Create one build with Distribution profile.
- Upload build on store. Add build to current version. Add In-App-Purchases to the version on iTunes Connect.
- Then try to test, if still not then submit app once then cancel it. then after try to test on your device.
- Make sure when you test with sandbox user, you need to sign-out from your already logged in account from device settings, and login with sandbox ID.
- some screenshots might be helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing that was a stumbling block for me was that I hadn't completed my banking information. After that step was finished, the product IDs started to work.

Comment: Must we upload binary then submit?

Answer (score 2):

please check these settings
 capabilities --> In-App purchase --> set to "ON"
and at developer.apple.com--> enable In-App purchase for App ID.

and please test app on Device instead of simulator.

[image: Xcode-->capabilities]

[image: developer.apple.com--> enable In-App purchase]

Comment: Thanks for the response Mahial Singh.. but I already enabled In-App Purchase in iTunes in Certificates and provisioning Profiles.... And I also enabled  In-App Purchase in xCode -> Capabilities... THIS IS ALREADY DONE.

Comment: then you have to check product identifier. the product identifier match is case sensitive.

So, if you've created a product on Apple with an identifier of say

com.yourcompany.product1
and you call the product request with a product identifier of

com.yourcompany.Product1
Your list will be returned with zero products.

Comment: Or you can try with 

productID = "MyProduct"

 let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs as! Set<String>)

rather than

 productID = "com.company.ProjectName.MyProduct"

Comment: // The ProducID in this code and ProducID on iTunes are the SAME. ✔️  .....  I already mentioned in code comment. see the second line. BOTH ARE SAME.... I know it well: the product identifier match is case sensitive...  I THINK PROBLEM IS ABOUT THAT WARNING............